# How to detect if a userdata has "environment table"?

Tags: lua

In Lua 5.1, one can associate an *environment* table with a userdata. This lets us add "fields" to individual userdatas.

The obvious approach would be to create this environment table, possibly an empty one, *right when you create the userdata*. However, in my application there'll be many userdatas that won't necessarily need this environment table and they come and go out of existence rapidly. I don't want the overhead of creating so many temporary empty tables that won't be used.

So, instead, I thought of creating the environment table only when I detect that the userdata doesn't already have one created by me.

The problem is that in Lua 5.1 the default environment table isn't `nil`. It's supposedly the global table, `_G` (I wonder how on earth this is useful). So, supposedly, I'd test for a non-initialized userdata by doing:

```c
/* 'index' is where my userdata is */
lua_getfenv(L, index);
initialized = lua_rawequal(L, index, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX);
```

Now, my question:

Do I need to use LUA_ENVIRONINDEX, or LUA_GLOBALSINDEX? Or do I need to do something else? Is this test going to work in **absolutely any** scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you will encounter either the global table `_G` or the `package` table as default environment for userdata depending on the function environment of the C function calling `lua_newuserdata` (see [here](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.9)). Userdata in extension modules loaded via `require` usually have the `package` table as default environment, because `require` has that table set as environment, and it is inherited by all registered C functions and the userdatas created within them. `newproxy` on the other hand sets `_G` as default environment.

In principle you could get any table as default environment if someone changes the function environment of C functions (which is pretty rare). In practice it's probably enough to check for `_G` and the `package` table. For that you need valid indices for the environment table of your userdata, the `package` table, and the globals table:

```
lua_getfenv( L, index ); /* pushes the environment of the ud to stack */
lua_getglobal( L, "package" ); /* pushes the package table to stack */
/* the globals table is always available at LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, so no need to push
 * anything ... */
hasdefaultenv = lua_rawequal( L, -2, -1 ) /* compare env to package table */
             || lua_rawequal( L, -2, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX ); /* compare env to _G */
```

You probably want to save the `package` table somewhere (e.g. in an upvalue), so that no-one can mess up your test by replacing the `package` table.

The most robust solution however would be to set one unique shared dummy table as environment when you create your userdatas (you could use `_G` for that), and check for and replace that dummy table later if necessary.

Btw., `LUA_ENVIRONINDEX` is for getting the environment of the [currently running C function](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#3.3), not for getting the environment of a userdata.

Comment: Excellent answer. The suggestion to explicitly set the environment to `_G` is a very good one.